# Какой предлог правильный: В или НА?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлог

Почему говорим "сидеть в Макдоналдсе", но если Хуторок, то будет "сидеть на Хуторке"? 
Разъяснение: Я сам не уверен, что так правильно сказать. Я услышал такое и сам удивился.

Comment: Кто так говорит? Где вы нашли "сидеть на Хуторке"?

Comment: То есть, это не правильно?

Comment: Так говорили в Украине. Я сам удивился, по этому задал такой вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по вопросу, "Хуторок" - название кафе. Поэтому его название должно писаться в кавычках. Мы сидим **в** кафе, и это **в** сохраняется, когда мы называем кафе по имени.

**Сидеть в "Хуторке".**

Дaже если бы кафе называлось "Скамейка", следовало бы говорить: «Сидим **в** "Скамейке"»

Comment: Московский ресторан Хуторок пишут почему-то без кавычек. А омский - с ними. Это из того, что всплывает на первых страницах.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что нет. У вас написано с заглавной, следовательно это имя собственное. И оно требует **"[сидеть] В"**. Причем, неважно, в каком значении "сидеть": проводить время, занимать оборону или жить долгое время безвыездно.

Если бы это был просто хуторок, не имя, а тип населенного пункта, то предлог "на" был бы правильным и это историческая норма (ср. на даче, на выселках), хотя и "в хуторке" сейчас уже встречается.

Но при использовании родовых слов именования населенных пунктов (как и других имен нарицательных) в качестве имен собственных предлог не обязан быть тем же.

*Сидеть на хуторке* (на неком маленьком хуторе) и, возможно, *сидеть в хуторке* (современное, разговорное).

Но: ***сидеть в Хуторке*** (в населенном пункте - их много таких), ***сидеть в "Хуторке"*** (в кафе, клубе) и т.д.

В украинском, кстати, то же самое. Возможно, вы услышали некую стилизацию или умышленное сведение имени собственного к нарицательному (исходному родовому слову) - иронию, одним словом.